# Play method for TicTacToe java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

So we got an excercise and need to write a tictactoe class, we need to work with a 2d int array as the board and 2 players, one has a "1" as the "X" and the other one a "2" as the "O", "0" is for empty field. Now we need to write a method for the players to actually set something on the field, but all I can think about is stuff to do with a string or char board and nothing really with an int board. How do you realize this setting of a problem with a number on an int board? Thanks for any help!

I already got a method which checks if there's any free spot available on the board anyways, which should be correct.

```java
public class TicTacToe extends BasicBoard implements Game {

    int PlayerA = 1;
    int PlayerB = 2;
    int empty = 0;
    private int row, column;
    private int[][] board = new int[column][row];


    public boolean isboardfull(int row, int column) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= column; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= row; j++)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == PlayerA || board[i][j] == PlayerB)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
     }
     public  void playerturn(){
        if (!isboardfull(row, column))

     }
}
```

Comment: What's the deal? Why can't you write a 1 or 0 on a int variable? Also, you should initialize the board to a non-0-or-1 value, tipically they use `-1`

Comment: Your question is very vague, also the conditions for your exercise are not very detailed. Are players supposed to play by entering values, or do you only have to write methods? Anyway, you can write into 2d arrays like this: `board[1][2] = 1;`

Comment: `private int[][] board = new int[column][row];` The variables `row` and `column` are zero here (the default value of `int`). You should initialize them: `final int column = 3; final int row = 3; private int[][] board = new int[column][row];`

Comment: How do you expect players to communicate? By writing the x,y coordinates of the position to mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TicTacToe` class extends from the `BasicBoard` and `Game` classes but you have not provided them. I assume that these classes give you methods to render the board and control the game evolution but since we don't have them I have included something similar (and simple) in my example (to demonstrate how it works). You can skip the `game`, `printBoard`, `resetBoard`, and `endGame` methods if these are provided by the `BasicBoard` and `Game` classes.

Here is a list of assumptions I have made:

- The players are asked for the coordinates where to play
- The game ends when the board is full. A more complex version should check every iteration of the game if one of the players has won.

And here a general explanation of my approach:

- The mapping between X and O to 1 and 2 is set to `static constant` since this will never change.
- The number of rows and columns may vary between executions and its parametrized in the `TicTacToe` constructor.
- The players fill the information through the standard input when prompted.
- The `game` function asks for the players to move and renders the board (on the standard output) until the board is completely filled.
- **The `isBoardFull` function checks if there are empty slots on the board or not. Thus, if we find an empty slot we know it is not full, otherwise we need to keep searching for empty slots. If we search through all the board and there are no empty slots, then it is full. (in my opinion, this part is miss-written in the coded you provided)**
- **The `playerTurn` function asks for the coordinates where the player wants to play and fills the board. To do so, we scan 2 lines of the standard input, convert them to `int` and check if the position is empty and within bounds. If so, we mark the position with the player number.**

The code:

```
public class TicTacToe {

    private static final int PLAYER_A = 1;
    private static final int PLAYER_B = 2;
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;

    private final int numRows;
    private final int numColumns;
    private final int[][] board;

    private final Scanner inputScanner;


    public TicTacToe(int numRows, int numColumns) {
        // Retrieve board sizes
        this.numRows = numRows;
        this.numColumns = numColumns;

        // Instantiate board
        this.board = new int[numRows][numColumns];

        // Initialize board
        resetBoard();

        // Initialize the input scanner (for player choices)
        this.inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void game() {
        // Initialize the game
        int numMoves = 0;
        printBoard(numMoves);

        // Play until the game is over
        while (!isBoardFull() && !hasPlayerWon()) {
            // A or B player should move
            int currentPlayer = (numMoves % 2 == 0) ? PLAYER_A : PLAYER_B;
            playerTurn(currentPlayer);

            // We increase the number of moves
            numMoves += 1;

            // We render the board
            printBoard(numMoves);
        }

        // Check winner and close game
        endGame();
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numRows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.numColumns; ++j) {
                this.board[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    private void printBoard(int currentMove) {
        System.out.println("Move: " + currentMove);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numRows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.numColumns; ++j) {
                System.out.print(this.board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // A new line to split moves
        System.out.println();
    }

    private boolean isBoardFull() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numRows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.numColumns; ++j) {
                if (this.board[i][j] == EMPTY) {
                    // If there is an empty cell, the board is not full
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // If there are no empty cells, the board is full
        return true;
    }

    private boolean hasPlayerWon() {
        // TODO: Return whether a player has won the game or not
        return false;
    }

    private void playerTurn(int currentPlayer) {
        // Log player information
        System.out.println("Turn for player: " + currentPlayer);

        // Ask the player to pick a position
        boolean validPosition = false;
        while (!validPosition) {
            // Ask for X position
            int posX = askForPosition("row", this.numRows);
            // Ask for Y position
            int posY = askForPosition("column", this.numColumns);

            // Check position
            if (posX >= 0 && posX < this.numRows) {
                if (posY >= 0 && posY < this.numColumns) {
                    if (this.board[posX][posY] == EMPTY) {
                        // Mark as valid
                        validPosition = true;
                        // Mark the position
                        this.board[posX][posY] = currentPlayer;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Position is not empty. Please choose another one.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Column position is not within bounds. Please choose another one.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Row position is not within bounds. Please choose another one.");
            }
        }

    }

    private int askForPosition(String rc, int dimensionLimit) {
        System.out.println("Select a " + rc + " position between 0 and " + dimensionLimit);

        return Integer.valueOf(this.inputScanner.nextLine());
    }

    private void endGame() {
        // Close input scanner
        this.inputScanner.close();

        // Log game end
        System.out.println("GAME ENDED!");

        // TODO: Check the board status
        System.out.println("Draw");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe(3, 4);
        ttt.game();
    }

}
```

Example Output:

```
Move: 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 

Turn for player: 1
Select a row position between 0 and 3
4
Select a column position between 0 and 4
1
Row position is not within bounds. Please choose another one.
Select a row position between 0 and 3
1
Select a column position between 0 and 4
1
Move: 1
0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 

Turn for player: 2
.
.
.
Move: 12
2 2 1 2 
1 1 2 1 
1 2 1 2 

GAME ENDED!
Draw
```